# Solving a question using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

I'm using the fundamental theorem of calculus to try to solve the following problem...

If $f(x)=\int_0^{x^2}t^4 \, dt$, then what is $f'(x)$?

Using the fundamental theorem of Calculus I get $f'(x)= x^8$

Am i doing this right or no?

Comment: okay so the math equation didn't work at all. Ill try again.

Comment: I cant get the equations to look right

Comment: Did I fix your equations correctly?

Comment: You need to use the Chain Rule; try letting $u=x^2$ and using $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$.

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Thanks Ayman.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. This really helped me understand.

Comment: There is a general formula for such derivatives: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign (in your case, the integrand not depend on $x$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(t)=t^4$ and $G$ -antiderivative of $g$ $G'(t)=g(t)$. Then by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x^2} g(t) dt=G(x^2)-G(0)$$

Derive both sides (right side using chain rule):

$$f'(x)=(G(x^2)-G(0))=(x^2)'G'(x^2)=2xg(x^2)=2x \cdot (x^{2})^4=2x^{9}$$

Answer (score 3):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x^2}t^4dt = G(x^2)-G(0)$ for a differentiable function $G$. This implies that $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(G(x^2)-G(0))=2xG'(x^2)$. Since, $G'(x)=x^4$ we obtain $f'(x)=2x^9$. By the way, you can check your work by just evaluating the integral directly.

Answer (score 0):

recall that after integrating that $t$ disappears.

first, find $f$

$$f(x) = \int_0^{x^2}t^4dt = \frac{t^5}{5}\bigg|_0^{x^2}=\frac{x^{10}}{5}-0=\frac{x^{10}}{5}$$

then $f'$
$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \bigg(\frac{x^{10}}{5}\bigg)=\frac{10x^9}{5}=2x^9$$

Answer (score 0):

Just put $u=x^{2}$ and note that $$y=f(x) = \int_{0}^{u}t^{4}\,dt$$ and then by FTC we have $$\frac{dy}{du} = u^{4}$$ and then by chain rule we have $$f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot\frac{du}{dx} = u^{4}\cdot 2x = 2x^{9}$$